# How to pull image right in flexbox paragraph?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to create a simple paragraph with an image floating on the right side, text being wrapped around the image.

I thought I could do that with Flexbox.

Here is what I tried:

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-start; width: 100%">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/400/400?image=1029" style="margin-left: auto">
  <p>
    New York City has a population of approximately 8.2 million people. The New York Metropolitan Area, which spans lower New York, northern New Jersey, and southwestern Connecticut, has a population of 18.7 million, making it the largest metropolitan area
    in the U.S. As of 2014, it was one of the 15 largest metro areas in the world.
  </p>
</div>
```

But this creates this false result:

[image]

How to get the image float right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a textbook case for using the `float` property:

```css
img {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/400/400?image=1029">
  <p>
    New York City has a population of approximately 8.2 million people. The New York Metropolitan Area, which spans lower New York, northern New Jersey, and southwestern Connecticut, has a population of 18.7 million, making it the largest metropolitan areain the U.S. As of 2014, it was one of the 15 largest metro areas in the world. New York City has a population of approximately 8.2 million people. The New York Metropolitan Area, which spans lower New York, northern New Jersey, and southwestern Connecticut, has a population of 18.7 million, making it the largest metropolitan areain the U.S. As of 2014, it was one of the 15 largest metro areas in the world. New York City has a population of approximately 8.2 million people. The New York Metropolitan Area, which spans lower New York, northern New Jersey, and southwestern Connecticut, has a population of 18.7 million, making it the largest metropolitan areain the U.S. As of 2014, it was one of the 15 largest metro areas in the world.
  </p>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ng3a0v4x/2/)

With flexbox, you can align the image to the right, but you can't make the text wrap around it:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}

img {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/400/400?image=1029">
  <p>
    New York City has a population of approximately 8.2 million people. The New York Metropolitan Area, which spans lower New York, northern New Jersey, and southwestern Connecticut, has a population of 18.7 million, making it the largest metropolitan areain
    the U.S. As of 2014, it was one of the 15 largest metro areas in the world. New York City has a population of approximately 8.2 million people. The New York Metropolitan Area, which spans lower New York, northern New Jersey, and southwestern Connecticut,
    has a population of 18.7 million, making it the largest metropolitan areain the U.S. As of 2014, it was one of the 15 largest metro areas in the world. New York City has a population of approximately 8.2 million people. The New York Metropolitan Area,
    which spans lower New York, northern New Jersey, and southwestern Connecticut, has a population of 18.7 million, making it the largest metropolitan areain the U.S. As of 2014, it was one of the 15 largest metro areas in the world.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Good to know that there are cases where `float` is still relevant.

Answer (score 0):

just added `order: 2` to `img`

```css
div img {
  order: 2
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-start; width: 100%">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/400/400?image=1029" style="margin-left: auto">
  <p>
    New York City has a population of approximately 8.2 million people. The New York Metropolitan Area, which spans lower New York, northern New Jersey, and southwestern Connecticut, has a population of 18.7 million, making it the largest metropolitan area
    in the U.S. As of 2014, it was one of the 15 largest metro areas in the world.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer said, that's exactly what the `float` property if for.  If you *did* want to do this with Flexbox, you'd use:

```
flex-direction: row-reverse
```

Which cause each block level item inside the "flexed" element to display from right to left.